# Can I use jest.fn() related checks with axios-mock-adapter?

Tags: jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

I'm using `axios-mock-adapter` and I want to know if I can set it up so that I can also make assertions like `expect(MockAdapter.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);`

I've tried the following:

```js
// test
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
import { fetchProducts } from "../src/redux/actions/productActions";

describe("fetchProducts", () => {
  const mock = new MockAdapter();
  it("fetches the products", async () => {
    const x = await fetchProducts();
    expect(mock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://www.whatever.com");
  });
});

// function
import axios from "axios";

export async function* fetchProducts() {
  let data = await axios.get("https://www.whatever.com");
  return data;
}
```

And it says

```
    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has value: undefined
```

If I add a `./__mocks__/axios.js` file, I immediately get

```
    TypeError: axios.create is not a function

    > 1 | import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
        | ^
      2 | import { fetchProducts } from "../src/redux/actions/productActions";
```

Is there a way to do this, or is it either mock my own implementation of `axios` functions, or use `axios-mock-adapter` without access to it as a jest mock function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a spy like so:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(mock, 'onGet');

mock.onGet('https://www.whatever.com').reply(200);

// only if mock client has been called with https://www.whatever.com the test will pass
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```